# facebook authentication

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth, window, parent-child

I am trying to authenticate my website (not hosted anywhere but on my desktop) using oauth. I am looking to retrieve access_token
I registered my app with FB to get the appid.
In the redirect uri I am using https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html.

Problem is .. when the child window authenticates and redirects to a success, how do I control that from the parent window and retrieve the access token from the child window.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do client side authentication on you local pc. If you want to do server side authentication you will need a redirect uri which points to your website.

Comment: put pointing to my website means I would need to register the website with facebook, which I dont have! Is there a workaround for this..

Comment: Anyways aint I doing a client side authentication. I am using HTML/javascript

Comment: I've done some searching. And it's possible to get an access_token by using the facebook JS Api. After the popup the user will be logged in and you can subscribe to these events. Next to that you can get the login status which gives the token. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/